# Dynamic binding, Static binding, Pointer to function, deep meaning

Tags: c++, binding, polymorphism, virtual-functions, dynamic-binding

In static binding the decision of the method to be called is made at compile-time, in dynamic binding, the decision about the method to be called is made at run time.
Virtual methods are called with dynamic binding.
This means that during the compilation phase it is decided which is the function pointer of the virtual table that must be called.
Being a function pointer nothing more than a variable that contains the memory address of the function pointed to and is decided at compile time which pointer to call, in my opinion, it was therefore decided, indirectly, also the method that will have to be called in compilation phase.

So my question is:
Why is it said that in dynamic binding the decision of the method to be called is taken during execution, when in fact the entry of the virtual table was already selected during the compilation phase?

Comment: your premise is false: in general only at runtime it can be decided what function is called

Comment: The entry in a vtable is known at the compile-time, but which vtable to look at is known only at the run-time.

Comment: consider `void (Foo& f) { f.bar();}` when the compiler sees this function and `bar` is virtual it has no way to decide already at compiletime what function to call

Comment: @Evg ok so the position in the v-table is known at compile time, but the vtable pointer is initialized at run time.

Comment: what if the actual type of the instance depends on user input? I dont really understand what makes you think everything is readily known at compiletime

Comment: @ formerlyknownas_463035818 in fact I've said the the pointer to function, the entry, is selected in compile time, not the function itself.

Comment: btw even if you were right, your argumentation is backwards. vtables are an implementation detail. The c++ standard specifies how virtual functions are dispatched at runtime and vtables is the common implementation. Just because you can do something with vtables at compiletime does not make dynamic dispatch less runtime

Comment: The question came to me simply because pointing each entry to a specific function, and being already decided at the compile time, the entry to be invoked, I just could not understand what information was missing to select the correct method. That's the problem for me.

Comment: You don't which table to look at.

Comment: okok thank you Evg so can we say that the problem is in the vtable pointer ?

Comment: @Tony92, I don't really understand what the problem is. To call a virtual method you have to make an indirect call to `vptr[index]`, where `index` is known at the compile-time, and `vptr` is known at the run-time. `vptr[index]` is conceptually the same as `*(vptr + index)`. Even if you know one term at the compile-time, you don't know the sum. That's why is it dynamic binding, not static.

Comment: @Evg Could you show me with some assembly instruction what really happens ?

Comment: [Take a look](https://godbolt.org/z/zv4MmV). For example, a call to the third virtual function translates into `call [rax+16]`, where `rax` is vtbl pointer (first "hidden" data member that is initialized by a constructor), and `16` is the fixed offset (= `index * sizeof(void*)`).

Comment: @Evg can you help me with the syntax, why call  [QWORD PTR [rax]], and not
call qword ptr [RAX] or call [RAX].
If rax contains the memory address of the first entry of the table, shouldn't it be [RAX], what the sense of [ [rax] ] ?

Comment: Conceptually it is just `call [rax]`. Everything else is irrelevant to understanding and comes from Intel syntax conventions. Outer `[ ]` look absolutely redundant to me. If you uncheck the "Intel" box above the assembly code, you'll see `call *(%rax)`, which expresses the same assembly instruction using another syntax.

Comment: Ok thank you, you are helping me so much. 
So why isn't rax value known at compile time ?

Comment: @Tony92, how can it be known at compile time if it comes from the function argument? I give you an object, `rax` is its first data member. How can you known it before I give you the object?

Answer (score 0):

> Static binding happens when all information needed to call a function
>   is available at the compile-time. **Dynamic binding happens when all
>   information needed for a function call cannot be determined at
>   compile-time**.

This is the motivation because the decision of the method to be called is taken at runtime. In fact for a virtual function, the compiler doesn't know a priori which function have to call ( it could depend on the class that call the function ). So the compiler link the virtual table but the virtual table can point to a different function implementation depending on the class of the object. This is the information that the compiler at compilation-time doesn't know, and only at runtime is deployed.

For a more specific details a leave you some useful links:

[Difference between static and dynamic bindings](https://www.techiedelight.com/difference-between-static-dynamic-binding-cpp/)

[Early binding and Late binding](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/early-binding-late-binding-c/)

[Virtual functions and Runtime Polimorphism](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/virtual-functions-and-runtime-polymorphism-in-c-set-1-introduction/)

Taking as example this image:

[image]

if you use an instanced object of **class triangle** in a function where the parameters is an object of **class polygon** the compiler doesn't know a priori of which real class is the object ( if Triangle or Rectangle ) but at runtime if you call the method `area()` the virtual table point at the right method of the class.

Comment: I have read many articles of this type, unfortunately the only thing that is said is always the same:
dynamic binding -> run time decision
Static binding -> decision in compile time.
But it is never well explained how this occurs.
I posted the question to understand in detail what happens.

Comment: i add an example to better explain the concept

Comment: Ok so the problem is in the pointer to vtable, that is initialized at run time ?

Comment: I have seen your exemple.

Comment: the compiler create a virtual table for each class. In the case the compiler doesn't know a priori the function to call, at runtime the virtual table point to the right function

Comment: What I know is that every class that defines or inherits a virtual function has its own virtual table which is a static array of function pointers pointing to the correct method.
A vtable pointer is then added to the base class which is inherited in all derived classes, and which is initialized when the class object is created to point to the correct virtual table.

Comment: yes, what you know is all true. the mechanism you have described is the mechanism that do the work